# Switching the direction of DC current flow to a load

Tags: arduino, dc, oscillator

I am a beginner (Software field) trying to do some basics in electronics.

I have got a load and a power source like this

[image]

My requirement is just to switch direction of dc current to the load in a controlled way.

I mean just switch the positive and negative to the load dynamically based on situation.

For example for few seconds current flows from left to right and for next second I need to switch it.

So in my code I am deciding how long and when to switch. I am using arduino.

And in my scenario its not actually just micro seconds sometimes, not even seconds a direction stays there.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Use an H-bridge.

Comment: google  `drive DC motor both directions`

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/586543/12v-motor-controlled-by-3-3v-logic/586553#586553

Comment: Or use L298 IC/board.

Comment: @DKNguyen HBridge sounds awesome.. Thanks a lot for that.. I found a module. But that specific one only handles .8A which doesnt work in my case. So needs to find some modules more powerful Thanks a lot..

Comment: What is the load?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question how fast you need to switch or how often but if the requirements are fairly slow then you could use a DPDT (Double Pole, Double Throw) relay.

[image: Polarity changer]

Comment: I need to switch from one polarity to another in milliseconds or less.. But in one polarity it may stay sometimes little long (upto 4-5 seconds) and sometimes only few micro seconds